# BODY background image gets cut off on browser viewport

Tags: css, html, layout

**SOLVED**
I used the solution proposed by Roman below, based on adding an additional **DIV** with **position:absolute**, I tested it in IE7, IE8, IE9, Chrome and Firefox and seems to work fine!

So the layout now has 3 full background images (what I needed), and even you can use the **BODY** bg taking care of that will be cutted off to the browser's viewport height (still could be useful in some cases), **"three and and a half" bg images with "sticky footer" :)**

The only drawback I found its that the links in the #footerContent were not "clickable", I solved it using **position:relative** to this container.

I made the changes to the sample I provided and uploaded it to my Dropbox, In the case that someone else could find it usefull.
Thank you all for your answers.
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/512412/html_stackoverflow_solution.rar

---

I uploaded

I'm building a quite complex layout for a website where I need to have 3 background images covering the background of the web page. So I have one in the **HTML** style, one in the **BODY** style, and the final one in a **DIV** that it's the container for all the webpage elements (**#contenedor**)

I'm also sing a **"Sticky footer" technique**, to have the footer "glued" to the bottom of the page whern there are small contents in the "main content" area.

The problem that I have It's that the **BODY** bg image gets cut off to the viewport of the web browser, I mean, **It doesn't repeat-y below the visible area displayed when the page is loaded**, and the contents are "tall" enough to make the webpage scroll.

What I tried until now:

1. To add an additional container **DIV** surrounding all (that's ok for me), but doing that It brokes the "Sticky footer" (maybe I did not found the right way to do it... I don't know).
2. Force the **BODY** to be as tall as the **HTML** using:

   ```
   html>body {  
   min-height:100%;  
   height:auto;  
   height:100%; }
   ```

This solves the BODY issue, the image repeats but this also breaks the "Sticky footer"... :(

You can see a sample:
Index with "small contents" all OK... footer on bottom, etc.
http://carloscabo.com/bg/index.htm

Index page with tall contents (simple **BRs**), scroll down to see the cut on the BODY bg Image
http://carloscabo.com/bg/index_tall.htm

You can also download all the files of this sample in the following URL to do your own local test.
http://carloscabo.com/bg/stackoverflow_html.zip

Comment: Which browsers do you need to support? It looks terribly like you need to support IE6..

Comment: Chrome, Firefox and IE7+ (if possible).
I don't need IE6 :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a reason I don't quite catch, it seems that the body is stuck with a height of 100% of the viewport. It refuses to grow past this point, and does not inherit the real height of the whole page.

However, if you don't mind to add another helper div, you can easily solve the problem.

First lets start with the html:
- Add a helper div before the head section.

```
<div id="contenedor">

    <!--HELPER DIV GOES HERE: BACKGROUND FIX-->
    <div id="bgfix"></div>

    <header id="arriba">
        ...
    </header><!--header#arriba-->

    ...

<div class="push"><!--Sticky Footer Push--></div>
</div><!--contenedor-->
```

And now let's modify the CSS:
- Remove the background from the body, and put it into the new helper div like so.

```
body {
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%
    text-align:center;
//  background:url(../img/bg_body.png) center top repeat-y;
    color:#fff;
}

#contenedor {
    position:relative; /* For #bgfix to attach here */
    ...
}

#bgfix {
    background:url(../img/bg_body.png) center top repeat-y;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

And VOILA!
Hope it helps!!!

Comment: I tried this solution, It work fine for the "short" index:  
http://carloscabo.com/bg2/

But seems to fail the same way for the long one :(  
http://carloscabo.com/bg2/index_tall.htm

(Now the BG image is called "xtra"), maybe I did something wrong... I tested it on Chrome only.  
The files:  
http://carloscabo.com/bg2/html_stack.zip

Comment: Correction!
I missed the position:relative on the container...
I'll try it on the other web browsers, but seems to WORK!

Comment: Hahaha glad to help! I didn't try it in IE7/8 though. Please, tell us if it works.

Answer (score 3):

The solution I found for this problem is to set min-height to the

```
min-height: 900px;
```

900px was the actual height of the background image i used.

Answer (score 1):

I would need to see exactly what do you want to accomplish in order to help you better, 
but i will make my best giving you some tips in advance

- you shouldn't be applying a background to the `HTML` tag.
- dont play with the `height` property of your body, it will mess up the sticky footer, instead let body height grow naturally with content.
- `body` will grow with the content, but `html` wont. `html` tag IS NOT a container.